# FFTW - 1D FFT for 2D Array in C

Tags: c, fft, fftw

I am trying to implement to calculate a 1D FFT for each row of a 2D array in C.
Here is my code (m and n here are respectively the number of rows and the number of columns of the matrix):

```
int howmany;
int i;
int idist = 1;
int inembed;
int istride;
int j;
int m;
int n;
int odist = 1;
int onembed;
int ostride;
int rank = 1;

fftw_complex *in;
fftw_complex *out;

fftw_plan plan_forward;

m = atoi(argv[1]);
n = atoi(argv[2]);

howmany = m;
istride = n;
ostride = n;
inembed = n;
onembed = n;

in = fftw_malloc ( sizeof ( fftw_complex ) * m * n );
out = fftw_malloc ( sizeof ( fftw_complex ) * m * n );

for ( i = 0; i < ( m * n ); i++ )
{
    in[i][0] = m * n - i - 1 ;
    in[i][1] = 0 ;
}

printf("Print Initial Data: \n");
for ( i = 0 ; i < m ; i ++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        printf ( "  %12f\t", in[j + i * n][0]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

plan_forward = fftw_plan_many_dft(rank, &n, howmany,
        in, &inembed,
        istride, idist,
        out, &onembed,
        ostride, odist,
        FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftw_execute ( plan_forward );

printf("Print Result FFT:\n");
for ( i = 0 ; i < m ; i ++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        printf ( "  %4d  %12f  %12f\n", i, out[j + i * n][0], out[j + i * n][1] );
    }
    printf("\n");
}

fftw_destroy_plan ( plan_forward );

fftw_free ( out );
fftw_free ( in );
```

Here is the result with a 4 x 4 2D array:

```
Print Initial Data: 
 15.000000       14.000000       13.000000       12.000000  
 11.000000       10.000000        9.000000        8.000000  
  7.000000        6.000000        5.000000        4.000000  
  3.000000        2.000000        1.000000        0.000000  
Print Result FFT:
 0     36.000000      0.000000
 0     32.000000      0.000000
 0     28.000000      0.000000
 0     24.000000      0.000000

 1      8.000000     -8.000000
 1      8.000000     -8.000000
 1      8.000000     -8.000000
 1      8.000000     -8.000000

 2      8.000000      0.000000
 2      8.000000      0.000000
 2      8.000000      0.000000
 2      8.000000      0.000000

 3      8.000000      8.000000
 3      8.000000      8.000000
 3      8.000000      8.000000
 3      8.000000      8.000000
```

Can anyone please tell me why I have wrong results? I might have called fftw_plan fftw_plan_many_dft in the wrong way but I can not see it.

Comment: From the documentation, it seems that `fftw_plan_many_dft` assumes that the 2D array is represented by a continuous *1D* array, where the rows are stored in sequence.

Comment: wouldn't it have been a great idea to call 'm' and 'n' by the meaningful names `numRows` and `numColumns`?